# Unknown auth_key in Pusher - Laravel 6.2

Tags: php, laravel, pusher

I know this question has been asked before on stackoverflow, yet it didn't resolve the problem. And I don't see anything wrong in the code.

In my .env file I have the following:

```
PUSHER_APP_ID={settings from pusher getting started - laravel page}
PUSHER_APP_KEY={settings from pusher getting started - laravel page}
PUSHER_APP_SECRET={settings from pusher getting started - laravel page}
```

I have installed latest `pusher/pusher-php-server` (4.1).

My broadcasting config is:

```
'pusher' => [
     'driver' => 'pusher',
     'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
     'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
     'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
     'options' => [
          'cluster' => 'eu',
          'useTLS' => true
      ],
 ],
```

For the application I'm building I don't have a logged in user but I connect 2 devices by generating a hash. The hash is the channel name.

So I have in my channels

```
Broadcast::channel('{device}');
```

I have created a event to broadcast:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcastNow;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class ReadyForServing implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    protected $channelName;

    public $message;

    public function __construct($channelName, $message)
    {
        $this->channelName = $channelName;
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return [$this->channelName];
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'ready';
    }

}
```

And calling it like:
`event(new ReadyForServing($device->hash, ['test' => 'test']));`

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong to cause this error. Anyone that can set me in the right direction?